# how can i change size of spinner which is added via codes?

Tags: android, spinner

i am workin' on a project which is similar dictionary knowledge tester. I want 2 add language names to spinner via codes but I have a problem and it drives me crazy.

I have no problem when I use the part which is marked below "1" but on the other hand if I use the part which is marked "2", it gives an error. at the same time if I use  "1" it looks like fullscreen but i have not found the way to change its size to smaller.

Please help me guys, thanks in advance.

1)`Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
setContentView(spin);`

2)`Spinner spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spin2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
setContentView(spin2);`

Comment: Could You provide more code? From '2' code it looks like setContentView() should be called before trying to call findViewById().

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using it in 1 you are setting the view of the spinner to be the only view visible.

What you need is to define the view in an XML file and then set that as the content view

eg main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your .java file

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //setting up the adapters
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    //adding things to the adapters
    dataAdapter.add("English");
    dataAdapter2.add("Spanish");

    //setting the spinners up from their id in the XML file
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    //setting the spinners adapters
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);      

}
```

That should do it, if I interpreted the question wrong just reply in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem. Problem was that i added relative & linear layout at the same time and program could not access to spinner correctly. Now i delete linear layout and add only relative layout and design my screen. There is no problem now on. Thanx everybody who was interested in this topic and gave an answer.